# How to organize a simple spring boot project?

Tags: spring-boot

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializr and I don't know if I'm doing the right thing in this project.
In this project I'll be using hibernate and thymeleaf.

```
com.demo.example
com.demo.example.controller 
com.demo.example.model 
com.demo.example.repository 
com.demo.example.service
```

Comment: Please let us know the exact problem. However looking into your package structure it looks right. I too use Spring Initializ plugin from Intellij and it always works fine

Comment: I was not sure about the packages but I just found this page and it looks right https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf